# Software Transactional Memory in Scala

Tags: scala, stm, dotty

I found this old, circa 2015, page:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2/java/stm.html

Fast forward to now and I can see that such a feature hasn't been incorporated in the language and this library seems to be unmaintained:
https://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/

Any other info I should be aware of?

Comment: https://timwspence.github.io/cats-stm/ & https://zio.dev/reference/stm/stm.md/

Comment: You have [zio](https://zio.dev/) which has [zio-STM](https://zio.dev/reference/stm/) or you also have [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) with [cats-stm](https://timwspence.github.io/cats-stm/)